# Zooming to point of interest

Tags: math, opengl, graphics

I have the following variables:

- Point of interest which is the position(x,y) in pixels of the place
  to focus.
- Screen width,height which are the dimensions of the window.
- Zoom level which sets the zoom level of the camera.

And this is the code I have so far.

```
void Zoom(int pointOfInterestX,int pointOfInterstY,int screenWidth,
   int screenHeight,int zoomLevel)
{   
glScalef(1,1,1);
glTranslatef( (pointOfInterestX/2) - (screenWidth/2), (pointOfInterestY/2) - (screenHeight/2),0);

glScalef(zoomLevel,zoomLevel,1);
}
```

And I want to  do zoom in/out but keep the point of interest in the middle of the screen. but so far all of my attempts have failed.

Comment: Zooming is going to change your projection matrix.  Are you using gluPerspective?

Comment: Thanks , but how do i center the screen again to the point of interest ?

Comment: You want to start rendering your frame by setting your projection matrix using gluPerspective.  If you do that, then you can change your zoom amount using the fovy parameter.  Whatever is in the center of the screen will stay in the center.

Comment: hmmm seems difficult to use :S edit : i use ortho btw

Comment: I use this version:

    glOrtho( 0, WindowW, WindowH, 0, -1, 1 );

Comment: gluOrtho2D(0,WindowW,WindowH,0); didn't help either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the rendering of your frame like this:

```cpp
 glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 GLdouble left = (0 - pointOfInterestX) / zoomLevel + pointOfInterestX;
 GLdouble right = (WindowW - pointOfInterestX) / zoomLevel + pointOfInterestX;
 GLdouble bottom = (WindowH - pointOfInterestY) / zoomLevel + pointOfInterestY;
 GLdouble top = (0 - pointOfInterestY) / zoomLevel + pointOfInterestY;
 glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, -1, 1);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
```